# AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool is not animating custom properties during export with AVAssetExportSession

Tags: ios, macos, avfoundation, core-graphics, core-animation

I'm trying to add an **animated** `CALayer` over my video and export it with `AVAssetExportSession`.

I'm animating the layer using `CABasicAnimation` set to my custom property.
However, it seems that `func draw(in ctx: CGContext)` is never called during an export for my custom layer, and no animation is played.

I found out that animating standard properties like `borderWidth` works fine, but custom properties are ignored.
Can someone help with that?

```swift
func export(standard: Bool) {
    print("Exporting...")
    let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    //composition.naturalSize = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
    
    // Video track
    let videoTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video,
                                                 preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID(1))!
    let _videoAssetURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "emptyVideo", withExtension: "mov")!
    let _emptyVideoAsset = AVURLAsset(url: _videoAssetURL)
    let _emptyVideoTrack = _emptyVideoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0]
    try! videoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: _emptyVideoAsset.duration),
                                    of: _emptyVideoTrack, at: .zero)
    
    // Root Layer
    let rootLayer = CALayer()
    rootLayer.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: composition.naturalSize)
    
    // Video layer
    let video = CALayer()
    video.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: composition.naturalSize)
    rootLayer.addSublayer(video)
    
    // Animated layer
    let animLayer = CustomLayer()
    animLayer.progress = 0.0
    animLayer.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: composition.naturalSize)
    rootLayer.addSublayer(animLayer)
    
    animLayer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    animLayer.borderWidth = 0.0
    let key = standard ? "borderWidth" : "progress"
    let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: key)
    anim.fromValue = 0.0
    anim.toValue = 50.0
    anim.duration = 6.0
    anim.beginTime = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero
    anim.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    animLayer.add(anim, forKey: nil)
    
    // Video Composition
    let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition(propertiesOf: composition)
    videoComposition.renderSize = composition.naturalSize
    videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 30)
    
    // Animation tool
    let animTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: video,
                                                       in: rootLayer)
    
    videoComposition.animationTool  = animTool
    
    // Video instruction > Basic
    let videoInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    videoInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: composition.duration)
    videoComposition.instructions = [videoInstruction]
    
    // Video-instruction > Layer instructions
    let layerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack)
    videoInstruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction]
    
    // Session
    let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition,
                                             presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)!
    exportSession.videoComposition = videoComposition
    exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    var url = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\(arc4random()).mov")
    url = URL(fileURLWithPath: url.path)
    exportSession.outputURL = url
    exportSession.outputFileType = .mov
    _session = exportSession
    
    exportSession.exportAsynchronously {
        if let error = exportSession.error {
            print("Fail. \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Ok")
            print(url)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let vc = AVPlayerViewController()
                vc.player = AVPlayer(url: url)
                self.present(vc, animated: true) {
                    vc.player?.play()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CustomLayer:

```swift
class CustomLayer: CALayer {
    
    @NSManaged var progress: CGFloat
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    
    override init(layer: Any) {
        let l = layer as! CustomLayer
        super.init(layer: layer)
        
        print("Copy. \(progress) \(l.progress)")
        self.progress = l.progress
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    override class func needsDisplay(forKey key: String) -> Bool {
        let needsDisplayKeys = ["progress"]
        if needsDisplayKeys.contains(key) {
            return true
        }
        return super.needsDisplay(forKey: key)
    }
    
    override func display() {
        print("Display. \(progress) | \(presentation()?.progress)")
        super.display()
    }
    
    override func draw(in ctx: CGContext) {
        // Save / restore ctx
        ctx.saveGState()
        defer { ctx.restoreGState() }
        
        print("Draw. \(progress)")
        ctx.move(to: .zero)
        ctx.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width * progress,
                                y: bounds.size.height * progress))
        ctx.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
        ctx.setLineWidth(40)
        ctx.strokePath()
    }
}
```

Here's a full sample project if someone is interested:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/evkm60wkeb2xrzh/BrokenAnimation.zip?dl=0

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @CentrumGuy no, but I talked to Apple and they did confirm it "looks like a bug". Unfortunately that's all I know :<